# Taylor series with mixed derivative

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \rightarrow f(x,y)$ a continuous, derivable function. Let $u := (x,y)$. Now, if you have $f(x+a,y+b) $with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ (and close enough to zero) , then by using Taylor series, it follows:
$$f(x+a,y+b) = f(x,y) + a \dfrac{ df(x,y)}{dx} + b \dfrac{ df(x,y)}{dy} + \mbox{some higher order terms}$$
but does there exist a 'kind of' a taylor series such that:
$$f(x+a, y+b) = f(x,y) + c \dfrac{df(x,y)}{du}?$$

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $df/du$ ?

Comment: just $df/ d(x,y)$ and $d(x,y)$ like in a twodimensional integral $\int f(x,y) d(x,y)$